# What is this map and how can i use it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I"m using a ripped model and there is this map called FXM. all the wiki says is

> These are utilized for special shader effects. Their uses vary
> instance to instance. These commonly end with Fxm

This is what it looks like with my node setup.
[image]

[image]

And this is what it looks like in game

[image]

[blend file of basic scene with jacket and nodes all set up (becides fxm)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19BDTbkoYJyOYZyUz34S3Nt_R9Skf8JVe/view?usp=sharing)
all images are packed

Comment: All I can find is that FXM is a MessiahStudio Motion file (likely rig and animations). I'm not sure blender can manage such a filetype.

Comment: The image looks like a mask. The value range seems to go from 0 to about 0.8  You could use it for the *Metallic* slot to exclude the cuffs and embroidery of the jacket and make it look more like fabric, while the other parts take on a metallic appearance like in the reference image. For some reason, the zipper is excluded and looks non-metallic (artistic freedom, plastic?), example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBAmJ.jpg